# first click on a check box then active button

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i have this code

```
if($('#checked').prop('checked', true);){
                            $("#signin_submit").prop('disabled', false)
                        }
                        else{
                        alert "Please Select One Or More And Then Click On This Button" 
                        }
```

and my button code

`<input name="deadmins" id="signin_submit" type="submit" value="Remove" disabled="disabled"  />`

i want user first click and check one or more and button disabled remove...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Try using if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )` rather than `if($('#checked').prop('checked', true);)`

Comment: What version of Jquery are you using? Shouldn't the button be disabled="true"?

Comment: i used 1.9 version can you explain me on jsfiddle ?

Comment: Here you go: [Let me know if you have any questions](http://jsfiddle.net/5z87e/1/)

Comment: Glad I was able to help!